# Spin-statistics theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education, pauli-exclusion-principle, spin-statistics

I am an undergrad physics student I was curious about the validity of the Pauli exclusion principle and found that spin statistics theorem gives the prrof of this principle . What background do I need to understand the proof of Pauli exclusion principle and the spin statistics theorem?

Comment: You need quantum field theory. It is proven in this book: http://inspirehep.net/record/290343 .